# pd.read_excel - import multiple sheets with different settings

Tags: excel, pandas, parsing, xlsx

I'm importing a very large (60+MB) xlsx file with numerous tabs.  Just one tab needs to skiprows, I've tried:

```
TuFile=pd.read_excel('TUp.xlsx', sheet_name=['T_up','Raw_Data','Base','Summary'], skiprows=[8,None,None,None])
```

Note: I'm trying to replicate: `TuFile = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[3], skiprows=8)` which works perfectly, except that I can't use the sheet name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load multiple sheets using `pandas.read_excel()` as you have done here, the sheets will be stored in a dictionary with the key being the respective sheet names. When the `skiprows` argument is passed in loading multiple sheets this way, the specified number of top rows or the list of rows given will be skipped from all of the sheets.

For example, if your code is modified as follows,

```
TuFile=pd.read_excel('TUp.xlsx', sheet_name=['T_up','Raw_Data','Base','Summary'], skiprows=[8])
```

This will skip the top 8 rows in loading your data for all of the sheets.

When a list of rows is specified,

```
TuFile=pd.read_excel('TUp.xlsx', sheet_name=['T_up','Raw_Data','Base','Summary'], skiprows=[1, 8])
```

This will skip the first and eighth rows in all of the sheets when loading the data.

Therefore, if you want the rows in just one of these sheets to be skipped, the best option would be to load that in separately by defining the sheet name and then load in the rest. Assuming that you want to skip rows only in the 'T_up' sheet and leave the rest intact, you could do something like this,

```
TuFile=pd.read_excel('TUp.xlsx', sheet_name='T_up', skiprows=[8])

TuFile=pd.read_excel('TUp.xlsx', sheet_name=['Raw_Data','Base','Summary'])
```

Comment: Poked around a bit more, skiprows is 0 based, so skiprows=[None,4,1] would actually ignore rows 2 & 5 in each sheet.  :(  Guess I'll have to load the one sheet separately as suggested.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, exactly. 0 actually gets rid of the header.